# How to convert a URL within a field into a photo?

Tags: livecode

In Livecode I am pulling information from a database using XML and organizing it using a repeat function. Therefore, for each node there is information such as photo, name, age, etc.

The photo, however, is read from the XML as the URL link of the photo. Is there a way to automatically load this URL and make the picture appear with the information also in this node following it?

```
on preOpenStack
 put url "http://www.petango.com/webservices/wsadoption.asmx/AdoptableSearch?authkey=XXXXXXXX&speciesID=&sex=&ageGroup=&location=&site=&onHold=&orderBy=&primaryBreed=&secondaryBreed=&specialNeeds=&noDogs=&noCats=&noKids=&stageID=" into  tURL
 put revCreateXMLTree( tURL, true, true, false) into tInfo
 put revXMLChildNames( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode", return, "XmlNode", true) into tChildren
 repeat for each line tChild in tChildren
  add 1 to x
  put revXMLChildNames( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&backslash, return, "adoptableSearch", true) into tAdoptable

  put revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&"/"&tAdoptable&"/Photo") into tData
  put "Name: " & revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&"/"&tAdoptable&"/Name") & return after tData
  put return after tData
  put return after tData
 end repeat

  put tData & return after tOutput
  set the text of field "tData" to tOutput

end preOpenStack
```

Answer (score 0):

You write that an XML node returns the URL to the photo, but you don't write which node this is. assume that

```
  revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&"/"&tAdoptable&"/Photo")
```

returns the URL. Put the URL into a variable and use it to set the text of an image object:

```
put revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&"/"&tAdoptable&"/Photo") into myUrl
put url myUrl into myPictureData
if the result is empty then
  set the text of img 1 to myPictureData
else
  beep
  answer error "Can't load picture."
end if
```

Comment: Mark, This did work, but it is just one picture in the middle of the screen which is switching between the pictures as it repeats to the next node. Is there a way to make each picture separate from the last?

Comment: @CElwell Yes there is. Read more about LiveCode and working with image objects. Read about the `rect` property and think about the design of your project. If you need help, it is probably best to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for hogging the thread after Marks excellent answer. But I usually just set the filename for the image:

```
repeat for each line tChild in tChildren
   add 1 to x
   ...
   put revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/"&tChild&"/"&tAdoptable&"/Photo") into myUrl
   create image ("image" && x)
   put it into tImageID
   set the filename of tImageID to myURL
   ...
end repeat
```

This will not check if the image loaded correctly but as you will not get any image anyway it is a easy solution.

Comment: There are some problems with this method, which you can solve if you're an advanced programmer. Therefore I decided to use a slightly more reliable and robust method.

Comment: I apologize as I did not see your answer. I understand what Mark is saying also here, but I also tried your method and ended up with the same issue of the images appearing in the middle of the application one on top of the other.

Comment: If you create images on the fly, well any control actually, they will be placed at the center and you need to move it to the correct position via code. If you have predefined images you can lock their size and position and they will keep both size and position.